# Ссылка в дельфи на exe файл

Tags: delphi

Здраствуйте! Можно ли в дельфи как то создать интерфейс с сылкой на ехе файл (екзешник скринсейвера) Прилагается картинка как бы это выглядело. [image]
Я хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки "запуск программы" открывался мой екзешник скринсейвер. А еще лучше будет если возможно добавить таймер, по истечению которого открывался бы ехе файл.
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Странный скринсайвер...
Для чего запускать ехе(какбэ скринсейвер), после закрытия приложения?

Answer (score 5):

Да такой механизм можно проделать! Просто нужно в кнопку вписать код!

```
ShellExecute(Handle,nil,PChar('Путь где находится программа.exe'),nil,nil,SW_RESTORE);
```

Да и не забудь вставить:

uses...
ShellApi

Надеюсь это то что нужно!

Comment: Да ну так тоже верно но просто я думаю легче будет вписать код в кнопу. 

ShellExecute(Handle,nil,PChar('Путь где находится программа.exe'),nil,nil,SW_RESTORE);
и что бы закрыть свою форму 
вписать в кнопку же полностью! 

ShellExecute(Handle,nil,PChar('Путь где находится программа.exe'),nil,nil,SW_RESTORE);
Form1.close;

Так будет наверное удобнее! :)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите [тут](http://articles.org.ru/lessond/les4.php) раздел "**Для продвинутых программистов: Запуск других приложений из вашего**" (*где-то в середине статьи*)

Еще советую открыть для себя ресурс [delphisources.ru](http://delphisources.ru/pages/faq.html), разобрано *очень* много вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

проще сделать так(если вся программа ваша):
создаете еще одну форму(например Form2), в событии OnShow главной формы вашей программы напишете:

```
Form2.ShowModal;
```

теперь при запуске программы эта форма перекроет основную,на нее добавьте кнопку, при нажатии на которую она закроется(Close), а основная автоматом откроется.
Я делфи уже плохо помню, но смысл думаю поймете.